# Is there an open dialog to select a file inside a Jar?

Tags: java, jar

I am looking for a dialog that will be able to browse to content of jar file (or even better allow me to browse the file system and then get into the jar file).

Ideally the dialog should return a classloader for the jar and the url of the selected resource.

Can anybody point me to some sample code to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: a jar file is a zip file.

Comment: you can change the file suffix to .zip and use unzip to open it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implements you own `FileSystemView` that will be able to go into ZIP/JAR files and then pass this implementation to `JFileChooser` constructor.  If you need more details, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: I hoped there was something out of the box. But this is the best answer so far. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

JAR is basically a zip file. You can open it with standard ZIP library for Java.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class JarAccess
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      if (args.length != 1)
      {
         System.err.println("usage: java JarAccess name_or_your_jar.jar");
         return;
      }
      try (ZipInputStream zis =
              new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0])))
      {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
         ZipEntry ze;
         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
         {
            System.out.println("Extracting: "+ze);
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ze.getName()))
            {
               int numBytes;
               while ((numBytes = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
                  fos.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[source](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362)

(code is untested, but logically it should work)

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a dialog box that display the hierarchical content of the zip file not how to read its content in a stream. I c ould write all that myself but I guess this must already exist. Note that the end of the article you linked shows more or less that. Unfortunately it depends a JavaFX and I am using Swing...